# PDE Separation of Variable: Question about Separation Constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have begun learning how to solve PDE using separation of variables. My textbook says the following:

Using separation of variables, we get

$\dfrac{T'}{\alpha^2 T} = \dfrac{X''}{X} = k$, where $k$ is a constant

$\implies T' - k \alpha^2 T = 0$ and $X'' - kX = 0$

Then the textbook goes on to say that

> However, we now make an important observation, namely, that we want the separation constant $k$ to be negative (or else the $T(t)$ factor doesn't go to zero as $t \to \infty$). With this in mind, it is general practice to rename $k = -\lambda^2$, where $\lambda$ is nonzero ($-\lambda$ is guaranteed to be negative).

I don't understand why he $T(t)$ factor doesn't go to zero as $t \to \infty$? The textbook does not justify this with an explanation.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: That's not a very good justification, in my opinion. What if the equation actually *has* solutions that blow up, wouldn't we be interested in knowing about that, instead of just ignoring them? A better argument is that $X''-kX=0$ (together with suitable boundary conditions) lacks nontrivial solutions if $k>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the equation

$$
T' - k\alpha^2T = 0 \tag{1}
$$

is

$$
T(t) = T(0)e^{k\alpha^2T} \tag{2}
$$

Recall your function has the form $u(t,x) = T(t)X(x)$, so that

$$
\lim_{t\to +\infty}u(t,x) = X(x)\lim_{t\to +\infty}T(t) = T(0)X(x)\lim_{t\to +\infty}e^{k\alpha^2 t} \tag{3}
$$

If you allow $k>0$ then this limit will not converge and the solution will blow up at large times, which usually is not what you want. But if you pick $k < 0$ then this limit will converge

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got that $T(t) = Ce^{k \alpha^2 T}$; where did you get $T(0)$ from?

Comment: @ThePointer $T(t) = Ce^{k\alpha^2\color{red}{t}}$ therefore $T(0) = Ce^{k\alpha^2 0} = Ce^0 = C$, that is $C = T(0)$

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy, the solution of $T'=k\alpha^2 T$ is $T(t)=T(0)\exp(k\alpha^2 t)$;

so if k is nonnegative, as $t\to \infty$ we get if $k=0$ that $T(t)=T(0)$, and if $k>0$ that $T(t)$ diverges unless $T(0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance.